# Can't right align pagination div

Tags: html, css

edit: I just removed what I had before, but I found out where the previous coder took this code from and I thought this would better ask my question. I'm trying to right align this pagination and it does not align properly.

here is a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Zd8sC/5/ 
here is the code:
html:

```
<ul id="pagination-clean">
<li class="previous-off">«Previous</li>
<li class="active">1</li>
<li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=5">5</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=6">6</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=7">7</a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="?page=2">Next »</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}

#pagination-clean li{
border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
font-size:11px;
list-style:none;
}
#pagination-clean li, #pagination-clean a{
border:solid 1px #DEDEDE
margin-right:2px;
}
#pagination-clean .previous-off,
#pagination-clean .next-off {
color:#888888
display:block;
float:left;
font-weight:bold;
padding:3px 4px;
}
#pagination-clean .next a,
#pagination-clean .previous a {
font-weight:bold;
border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
} 
#pagination-clean .active{
color:#00000
font-weight:bold;
display:block;
float:left;
padding:4px 6px;
}
#pagination-clean a:link,
#pagination-clean a:visited {
color:#0033CC
display:block;
float:left;
padding:3px 6px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#pagination-clean a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}​
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Zd8sC/22/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div
{
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

#pagination-clean
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't look like it did anything: I used <div style="display:block;text-align:right;">content</div>

Comment: edited my answer, without seeing your HTML this is my best guess. making the list inline will make it shrink to fit content, and text-align: right on its parent (the div) should send it to the right

Comment: it looks like it is turning into a block again, it is right aligned, but the content isn't on one line. Btw I appreciate your help!

Comment: I would say its all those "float: lefts" on your anchors cause otherwise this should work

Comment: I was browsing around and I just found out where the previous coder got this code, if possible can you look at my edited post and see from there?

Comment: I did some more stuff and the inline-block portion you gave me worked once I added it to pagination-clean li

Comment: now I'm just playing around with the active page and previous link

Answer (score 0):

set width of you div tag

```
<div style="width:200px;float:right"></div>
```

by this your div tags will not come one over another.

Comment: My pages come in dynamically so they can vary in size which is why I didn't use the width attribute

Comment: use width:50px;max-width:100px;overflow:hidden;

Comment: Hmm that didn't work either, it just stayed the same. I think it might be an issue with the other floating anchors I have on there like chris said, so I'll look into that